# Flask list of last used pages with sessions TypeError

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to make a list of pages that a user has visited recently, but I keep getting `TypeError: store_visited_urls() takes no arguments (1 given)`.
I don't know how an argument is given with it.

Python/Flask code:

```
app.secret_key = '/r/xd8}q/xde/x13/xe5F0/xe5/x8b/x96A64/xf2/xf8MK/xb1/xfdA7x8c'

def recentsites():
    session['urls'] = []

@app.after_request
def store_visited_urls():
    session['urls'].append(request.url)
    if(len[session['urls']]) > 3:
        session['urls'].pop(0)
    session.modified = True

@app.route('/')
def index():
    data = []
    if 'urls' in session:
        data = session['urls']
    return render_template('index.html', data=data)
```

Comment: Do you call `store_visited_urls()` somewhere else in your code, as what the error is telling you is that somewhere you are calling `store_visited_urls` with an argument e.g. `store_visited_urls(argument)`?

Comment: No, it does not get called somewhere else

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think that as a function, it automatically includes self as an argument. This argument is included as part of the call when you create a class.

make the definition `def store_visited_urls(self):` but continue to call it without an argument.

From the way it looks `session` must be defined in the class. Thus, you would reference `self.session` so that it will be picked up when the class is instantiated.

See [What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self) for an explanation.

I see that you are using a decorator See [Decorators I: Introduction to Python Decorators](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240808) and [A guide to Python's function decorators](http://thecodeship.com/patterns/guide-to-python-function-decorators/) or [Python Decorators](https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2012/04/29/python-decorators/) or [Primer on Python Decorators](https://realpython.com/blog/python/primer-on-python-decorators/)

Comment: That removed the error, thank you. One more (possibly stupid) question, how do I exactly reference self.session?

Comment: @NielsVanNimmen It depends if session is defined within the class or as a global variable. The sample question shows how to do this. If session is defined as an absolute global, you would not need it. If it is defined as a class variable it would be referenced within the class functions as `self.session` to apply to that instantiation.where you currently have `session` in your code.